# Trouble setting ul and li properly in html and css

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a listview using JQuery Mobile.

This is what it looks like on [mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lBfi.png).

I want the height of each li of the listview to grow automatically to accomodate the information and I also need the listview to be scrollable.

I found that if I give a fixed height to the listview, it becomes scrollable in both directions. But I want it to be only vertically scrollable and not horizontally.

I tried increasing the height of each li in the listview in my css, but the text would still only be displayed horizontally and it wont be contained within the li height and width.

If i change the overflow property, then the scrollable behaviour disappears.

What do I need to do?

Below is my css for the listview:

```
.listview-container
{
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}

.logsView-scroll
{

  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.listview-li
{
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

The html bit for the listview:

```
<div class="listview-container">
    <ul id="chickenLog" data-role="listview" class="logsView-scroll">
    </ul>
</div>
```

P.S. the li elements are programmatically appended through jquery by cloning the below template:

```
<ul id="chickenLog" data-role="listview" class="logsView-scroll">
    <li class="listview-li" id="aLog" data-theme="a"><span id="text"></span> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

li after it is [appended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQsDi.png)

Comment: Could you share the HTML after the `li`s are appended?

Comment: @HaldenCollier Posted at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Your provided code does not correspond to your screenshot. please provider a snippet that illustrates your issue

Comment: Could you also post the full CSS for these classes, that should give us enough to work with.

Comment: @VincentChinner I don't get what you mean. Which screenshot?

Comment: @HaldenCollier Some of those classes are automatically added by JQuery Mobile. The ones I posted are mine which I'm using to add margins and the scrollable behaviour

Comment: I just need my listview to be contained within the device width. I don't want the horizontal scrolling. I can't figure out how to remove that

Comment: I still need to see the styles that `jQuery` adds, as they might be the key to the issue. However if you want it to be vertically scrollable, try changing the `.listview-li` to `display: block;`

Comment: @HaldenCollier That works, but now I lose some of the text. Can't the li grow to accommodate the whole text?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "grow" is the text overflowing horizontally? Could you post a comment with a link to a screenshot.

Comment: you can add a style 'overflow-x: hidden' or use 'word-wrap' for the contents

Comment: @HaldenCollier After i put display: block, this is what i get https://ibb.co/jgyhHd5 

The rest of the text gets cut off and replaced with ...

Comment: @VincentChinner, I've managed to remove the horizontal scrolling. Now the only thing remaining is having the li contain all the text. See my above comment for screenshot

Comment: Try putting `white-space: normal; !important` in your `li` styles

Comment: No worries, happy to help!

Comment: @HaldenCollier Sorry Halden I have one last question. A bit different from this. 

If I want to have a div element sandwiched between two other divs, how can I do this?

Comment: It's fine, there are a lot of ways you can achieve this. Try making three `div`s with these styles: `display: inline-block; width: 33.333%;`. Let me know if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Conclusion:**

The `li` elements are `display: inline-block;`, this will cause them to go next to each other and overflow. You can get them to stack on top of one another by changing the `display` style to `block`.

Secondly, the `li` elements themselves have a `span` with the text inside. This will also overflow, so you need to give either your `li` the style `white-space: normal;` so the span can inherit this property or directly add it to your `span`.

(**Note:** When using libraries, they can often include their own `CSS`. So if you've put some styles on an element and they don't seem to be showing, this could be due to the fact that the library is overriding it. To combat this, you can put `!important` on the end of a style.)

**Example:**

```
.listview-li {
    display: block;
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

Comment: Also if you're using JQuery Mobile, I noticed that if your css isn't showing, it's most likely you're not initializing your page in the js. 
For example, $(document).delegate.("#page_id","pageinit",function(){});

I tested with and without this line and my css would only show up after I used that code.